# How to get data from a Quasar table row with the event @row-click

Tags: vue.js, row, quasar

How can the data associated with a row be obtained from a table with the @row-click event?

In the following example, how do I get the id and the name values of the clicked row?

```
<q-table
  title="Treats"
  dense
  :data="data"
  :columns="columns"
  row-key="id"
  @row-click="rowclick(evt, row)"
/>

(...)

  methods: {
    rowclick(evt, row){
      alert()
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this `@row-click="onRowClick"`.

```html
     <q-table
          title="Treats"
          dense
          :data="data"
          :columns="columns"
          row-key="id"
          @row-click="onRowClick"
        />
```

```js
      methods: {
        onRowClick (evt, row) {
          console.log('clicked on', row)
        }
      },
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/qBdaeGY